# Encode the AND (&) mark to not throw IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: java, android, urlencode

So i got this:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 56:` http://shopradar.hu/json/v1.0/getShopsList.php?text=ggdg&applang=hu

As far as i see it has problem with the AND (&) mark.

This is the code:

```
shopsUrl = Variables.baseURL + Variables.urlVersion + Variables.getShopsUrl + Variables.categoryParamUrl + kategoriaID;

shopsUrl = shopsUrl + "&applang=sk";
```

I tried to resolve this with:

```
String shopsUrl = ...;
shopsUrl = shopsUrl +URLEncoder.encode("&applang=hu", "UTF-8");
```

And with

```
String shopsUrl = ... +"&applang=hu";
shopsUrl = URLEncoder.enclode(shopsUrl , "UTF-8");
```

So i tried to encode the whole url and tried to encode the problem part none of them working.

How could i encode this? (In browser it is working, passing back an empty JSONArray)

Comment: What line of code is causing this problem? `URL url = new URL("http://shopradar.hu/json/v1.0/getShopsList.php?text=ggdg&applang=hu");` Works fine for me if thats whats causing an issue.

Comment: You tested from android or from browser ?